# Override google apps script 32768 characters limit on Exception: Argument too large: sql

Tags: javascript, mysql, google-apps-script, exception, upload

I used Google apps script GAS to upload my data to mysql server. If the statement is over 32768 characters, the function returns error. I think it is because of the Google cache issue for 16 bit in length. How to increase the limit? Here is my code:

```
mysql_statement = "INSERT INTO table (abc_id) VALUES ( xxx "
Logger.log(mysql_statement.length) // 32769
conn.createStatement().execute(mysql_statement)
```

Returns : Info
Exception: Argument too large: sql

Comment: There's no way to increase the limit you are mentioning. However, the cache [limit](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/cache/cache#putkey,-value) is the following `The maximum length of a key is 250 characters. The maximum amount of data that can be stored per key is 100KB.`. Is this the complete snippet you are using? Can you confirm you're not exceeding other limits?

Comment: I am not quite sure. When my statement has 32768 characters, I can execute but when there are 32769 characters, it returns error.

Comment: Can you share the whole code you are using?

Comment: I've hit the same issue. Had to reduce number of records I wanted to INSERT from 2300 to 600, so the SQL length was low enough.  Coupled with the fact that prepareStatement() doesn't work either, seems like Google doesn't take Sheets + Database seriously.

Answer (score 2):

TLDR; don't put your whole SQL statement into `prepareStatement`, but instead use it to create your template statement with `?` as placeholders for arguments and then feed those arguments with `setString()`

Taking your example, your SQL string `INSERT INTO table (abc_id) VALUES ( xxx` probably contains a large volume of data in the `VALUES` statement. Instead of putting the whole thing into `prepareStatement` like you did, you should refactor it like so:

```js
function main() {
  const valuesToInsert = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  const templateAr = ['INSERT INTO table (abc_id) VALUES (', ')'];
  const sqlStatement = createStatement(templateAr, valuesToInsert.length);
  executeSql(sqlStatement, valuesToInsert, ENV.connection);
}

function createStatement(templateAr, numArgs) {
  const ar = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < numArgs; i++) ar.push('?');
  return templateAr[0] + ar.join(', ') + templateAr[1];
}

function executeSql(sqlStatement, args, connection) {
  const { dbUrl, user, userPwd } = connection;
  const conn = const conn = Jdbc.getCloudSqlConnection(dbUrl, user, userPwd);
  const sqlQy = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStatement);
  if (args) {
    for (var i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
      sqlQy.setString(i + 1, args[i]);
    }
  }
  sqlQy.execute(args);
}
```

The error you encountered is only caused by putting too much data into `createStatement()`, but `setString()` can handle much higher volumes.

Check out [Writing to the database](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/jdbc#write_to_the_database) in the documentation.